# How to dispatch from actioncreator to reducer wihout error in one time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux

I am dispatching an image to firebase. Everything is successful and I can upload the image to firebase storage. But after I got success, my codes was suddenly dispatched an error one more time.By the way I logged some numbers to see what's going on and I got "1,2,3,4 then success and then failed error" on my console. How can I achive to upload image without getting failed error? I could upload but I also get error now.. Thank you in advance..
The error message says: "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance".

```
export const uploadPhoto = (uri, contentType = 'image/jpeg') => {
return async dispatch => {
    try {
        console.log('1');

        const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        const photoId = await uniqueIdGenerator();
        dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_START });
        console.log('2');

        const snapshot = await firebase.storage().ref()
            .child(`/photos/${userId}`)
            .child(photoId)
            .put(uri, { contentType });
        console.log('3');

        await firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users').doc(userId)
            .collection('photos').doc(photoId)
            .set({ url: snapshot.downloadURL });
        console.log(snapshot.downloadURL);
        console.log('4');

        await dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.downloadURL });
        console.log('5');

        Actions.pop();
        console.log('6');

    }
    catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_FAILED });
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
}
```

here is my reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: [],
    loading: false
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
    console.log('reducerState', state);
console.log('type,payload', type, payload);

switch (type) {
    case UPLOAD_START:
        return { ...state, data: payload, loading: true }
    case UPLOAD_SUCCESS:
        console.log('succesa girdi');
        return { ...state, data: [...state.data, payload], loading: false }
    case UPLOAD_FAILED:
        return { ...state, data: payload, loading: false }
    case GET_PHOTOS_START:
        return { ...state, data: payload, loading: true }
    case GET_PHOTOS_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, data: payload, loading: false }
    case GET_PHOTOS_FAILED:
        return { ...state, data: payload, loading: false }
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

**EDIT**

I have figured out the problem by remove all the dumy datas from my firebase storage. I use an emulator to test my app and I used same photos again and again. Most probably same photos causes a problem because I have not changed anything else in my app but now is working well.

Comment: What is the error exact message

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot to add it. The message says: 
"Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Comment: what your UPLOAD_SUCCESS is doing, can you post

Comment: hey, I have just added my reducer. By the way I post my photo url to reducer with UPLOAD_SUCCESS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your reducer

```
case UPLOAD_SUCCESS:
    console.log('succesa girdi');
    return { ...state, data: [...state.data, payload], loading: false }
```

to

```
case UPLOAD_SUCCESS:
    console.log('succesa girdi');
    return { ...state, data: payload, loading: false }
```

I think there is what the error is trying to warn you about. I'm not sure why you are trying to spread the state twice

**UPDATE**

in that case try this

```
case UPLOAD_SUCCESS:
    console.log('succesa girdi');
    let urls= state.data
    urls.push(payload)
    return { ...state, data: urls, loading: false }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer firstly. I need all of url in states therefore I tried to return all of previous url which were in state and new url which came from payload in an array. In this way I can show all url's in another page. If I do that like u said , I get only one url which I have just added but I can not take another url's.

Comment: Please try the updated answer. I'm not sure if that is correct so let me know if that works

Comment: I tried your new solution. Firstly I saw success on console then again suddenly catch block worked in actions and then upload_failed case in reducer worked. By the way I saw different error this time : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem.  I removed all dumy data from firebase storage. I was trying to test my app with same photos. Most probably same photo's causes a problem because I have not changed anything else. But now everything is working well. By the way thank you very much for your effort. I will update my question with this solution.